# POST request in iOS swift xcode 6

Tags: ios, http, post

I need to send my "email" and "password" to the serve and retrieve the response string.

I am new to swift and this is what I've tried (is this kind of syntax valid in a swift file?):

```
let email: NSString = EmailTxtFld.text
let url: String = "dating.nuindex.com/api/register.php"
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSString *messageBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"email", email];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setHTTPBody:[messageBody dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

[connection start];
```

Comment: Why are you not using `Afnetworking`? It's easy to use.

Comment: Why should one use AFNetworking, NSURLRequest, NSURLConnection, NSURLSession sre powerful api which are easy to use. I wouldnot suggest to use AFNetworking unless you have requirement to do so. Having said that I find AFNetworking quite nice and easy to use and I use it myself for day to day work.

Comment: Use NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:completionHandler: which is quite easy to use or you can also set NSURLConnection delegate and retrieve the dat from its delegate methods

Comment: You seem to be mixing Swift and Objective-C code here. Not sure why you're doing that. Also, these days you should really use NSURLSession. It's very simple to use and has some advantages over NSURLConnection.

Comment: The problem is I'm getting syntax errors like "expected member name or constructor call after type name". I have no clue what's going on. Can someone please help me with cleaning the code here?